# How to write a paraview python programmable source that makes a multiblockDataset?

Tags: paraview

I'm trying to write a python programmable source in Paraview that will create a `vtkMultiBlockDataSet`. I see that my python script in the programmable source gets a symbol called `output` which is of type `vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.CompositeDataSet`. How do I use that object to set the blocks? The only methods I see are to set things like points and cells.

My code creates a `vtk.vtkMultiBlockDataSet`. Can I somehow just set `output` to be this thing that I make?  Or do I need to copy? Thanks for any advice! -- Adam

Answer (score 2):

In the Programmable Source, remember to check that the "output data set type" is set to `vtkMultiblockDataSet`

At this point, you can just write

```
self.GetOutput().ShallowCopy(vtkMultiBlockDataSetCreatedByYourCode)
```

`output,inputs[0] ...`  are  *dataset_adapter* which allow you to easily access *vtkarrays* as numpy arrays (e.g, if inputs[0] is a *vtkpolydata*, you can just do `v2 = 2 * inputs.PointData['v']` instead of reading it as  `self.GetInput().GetPointData('v')` and converting to numpy array later - it's the same syntax as the python calculator), but I don't know if it's possible to access the blocks of `MultiBlockDataSet` (I just found an example in http://kitware.com/blog/home/post/713 )

Comment: Thanks very much! That's very helpful. I also figured out another way - self.GetOutputDataObject(0) is the output vtkMultiBlockDataSet - I just fill that.